# My api is called even when I am not at the bottom of my list while using infinite scroll pagination in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using infinite_scroll_pagination: ^3.2.0 for displaying my list of `Activity`. Now, the problem is that my list is loading continuously even when I am not at the bottom of my list. Like, all the data and pages are loaded even if I haven't scrolled for a bit. I want it to stop.

Here is my code:

```
final PagingController<int, Activity?> _pagingController =
      PagingController(firstPageKey: 0);
  int perPage = 10;
```

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pagingController.addPageRequestListener((pageKey) {
      _fetchPage(pageKey, filterData);
    });
  }

  Future<void> _fetchPage(int pageKey, FilterBottomSheetData? filter) async {
    debugPrint("Page number: $pageKey");
    try {
      final newItems = await _activityServices.getRecentActivity(
          offset: pageKey,
          branchId: filter?.branchId,
          gradeId: filter?.selectedGradeId,
          sectionId: filter?.selectedSectionId,
          subjectId: filter?.selectedSubject,
      );
      if (newItems!.result!.activities!.isNotEmpty) {
        final subR = await _activityServices.getSubjectMappingDetails(
            ids: newItems.result!.activities!
                .where((element) => element.subjectMappingId != null)
                .map((e) => e.subjectMappingId!)
                .toList());
        subjectMappingResult!.addAll(subR?.result ?? []);
      }

      int newEntries=newItems.result?.activities?.length??0;

      bool isLastPage = newEntries < perPage;

      debugPrint("${newItems.result!.activities?.length} and $perPage");

      if (isLastPage) {
        debugPrint("Here 1");
        _pagingController.appendLastPage(newItems.result!.activities!);
      } else {
        debugPrint("Here 2");
        final nextPageKey = pageKey + 1;
        _pagingController.appendPage(newItems.result!.activities!, nextPageKey);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      log(error.toString());
      _pagingController.error = error;
    }
  }
```

```
SingleChildScrollView(
            child: PagedListView<int, Activity?>(
              pagingController: _pagingController,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              primary: false,
              builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<Activity?>(
                firstPageErrorIndicatorBuilder: (context) =>
                    const Center(child: Text('Something went wrong')),
                noItemsFoundIndicatorBuilder: (context) => SizedBox(
                  height: ScreenSize.utilHeight * 0.75,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'No data found',
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .h3
                          .copyWith(color: Colors.grey[700]),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                firstPageProgressIndicatorBuilder: (context) => SizedBox(
                  height: ScreenSize.utilHeight * 0.9,
                  child: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                ),
                itemBuilder: (context, item, index) {
                  if (item != null) {
                    return RecentActivityCard(
                      subjectMappingResult: subjectMappingResult,
                      activity: item,
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Container(); // or any other widget that you want to use as a fallback for null values
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

I tried to set scroll listener in my initstate, but it didn't made any difference. I used this code:

```
_pagingController.addPageRequestListener((pageKey) {
      _fetchPage(pageKey, filterData);
      if (_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent ==_scrollController.position.pixels) {
        _fetchPage(pageKey, filterData);
      }
    });
```

While doing this, this error appears:

```
Null check operator used on a null value
```

And it is directing me to `maxScrollExtent`.